# Deploying a finished HTML web app with XULRunner?

Tags: web-applications, xul, xulrunner

We have a finished web app written in HTML+JS. It works fine with Chrome's Web App mode (as long  as SOP is disabled, to allow JSON requests from file:// URIs), but I don't really want to restrict myself to Chrome as only option (especially since Windows deployment can be a pain).

How do I deploy this app with XULRunner? The whole UI is already implemented, so the XUL code should be as minimal as possible (basically "here's the site, render it, and allow AJAX-requests to $domain"). Is there some tutorial how to do this? The ones I found all focus on pure XUL applications…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you check out [Webapp XUL Wrapper](https://github.com/neam/webapp-xul-wrapper). From the README:

Webapp XUL Wrapper is a collection of build scripts for packaging a webapp into distributable bundles for Mac, Windows, and Linux.

The end result is a standalone and offline version of your web application.

Included in the distribution package:

- A minimal XUL application with a main browser window and an about dialog
- A bundled [HTTP server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Httpd.js/HTTP_server_for_unit_tests)
- XULRunner 17 (Gecko 17)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, due to [perfomance issues](http://admin.tao.at/2012/09/04/rsa-encryption-in-javascript-and-c/) we've gone native long ago, but I'll have a look at it for the next time we'd need this.

Answer (score 3):

XULRunner is meant to run XUL-based applications, so the documentation focusing on them isn't wrong. However, if you only need that application to show a web app then your XUL application can be really simple. Basically, your only XUL file would look like this:

```xml
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    title="My Web App"
    id="webapp-window"
    width="800"
    height="600"
    persist="screenX screenY width height sizemode">
  <browser type="content-primary"
      src="index.html"
      flex="1"
      disablehistory="true"/>
</window>
```

That's a window that will remember its size and position and a browser element that will fill it completely. For reference: [`<xul:window>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/window), [`<xul:browser>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser).

And the `chrome.manifest` file would look like this:

```
content webapp content/
```

This declares the `content/` subdirectory as corresponding to `chrome://webapp/content/` - that's where you would put your main XUL file and the actual web application. Due to `chrome://` protocol being used the web application will run with full privileges meaning in particular that it will be allowed to use `XMLHttpRequest` on any domain (running a web app with full privileges isn't nice security-wise but that's the simplest way to disable the same-origin policy).

And finally the file `defaults/preferences/prefs.js` to tell XULRunner which window to open on startup:

```js
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeURI", "chrome://webapp/content/main.xul");
```

And that's pretty much already it. Have a look at the usual tutorials concerning `application.ini`.

Comment: Thanks, the web page now loads. Sorta. There are lots of rendering bugs which don't appear in normal Firefox, and if I start xulrunner with the -jsconsole argument, it just creates an empty, unresponsive window and then hangs up. :/

Comment: Rendering bugs as in "Relative paths expecting a different base URI" I guess?

Comment: No. Rendering bugs as in "one widget renders fine, but everything using ExtJS is just a smear of paint". And with jsconsole enabled, starting needs ten minutes(!), and every action in the error console needs one-two minutes to process.

Comment: Don't know, `content-primary` should entire that code runs exactly the same as in the regular browser - but some libraries might make assumption that are only valid for `http://` and not for `chrome://`.

Comment: Interesting. How would one package up and run this application on a target device?

Comment: @Chimera: That's entirely up to you. Normally you will use some installer to install it along with XULRunner - at least that's how Firefox, Thunderbird and pretty much any other XULRunner-based applications do it.